# MalformedPolicyDocument error on aws policy creation - terraform apply

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, identity-management

While inserting new **aws IAM policy** rule on terraform, `terraform plan` passes
as `terraform apply` fails on the statement ID.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "db_iam_policy_document" {
  version =  "2012-10-17"
  statement {
      actions   = ["rds:DeleteDBInstance"]
      effect    = "Deny"
      resources = [
        "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:db:*"
      ]
      condition {
        test     = "StringEquals"
        variable = "rds:db-tag/environment"
        values = [
          "production"
        ]
      }
      sid       = "don't_delete_production_dbs !"
    }
 }
```

The error presented on my CI/CD pipeline as the following:

```
Error: error updating IAM policy arn:aws:iam::123456789:policy/my_policy_name:  
MalformedPolicyDocument: Statement IDs (SID) must be alpha-numeric. 
Check that your input satisfies the regular expression [0-9A-Za-z]*
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform encountered: unmarshaling policy 1: value of type awspolicy.intermediatePolicyDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547207/terraform-encountered-unmarshaling-policy-1-value-of-type-awspolicy-intermedia)

Answer (score 1):

According to aws iam [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_sid.html) **The Sid element on aws policy**  ( statement id - which helps us to improve and convey a better documenation and readability to our iam rules )  **supports ASCII uppercase letters (A-Z), lowercase letters (a-z), and numbers (0-9).**
we need to change the sid attibute following the right rules and get rid of the incorrect chars ( on this example space, underscore,comma and exclamation mark ).

```
sid = "productionDBDeletionIsProhibited"
```